# Unexpected high 3g data usage on iPhone with mac

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos

It almost killed me 600MB in 20 minutes. I had my iPhone enabled the 'personal hotspot' function(as a wifi hotspot), so my mac can surf the internet through my iPhone. During that 20 minutes, I was just writing code in Xcode, there is no other application running. So how did all the data flow away? Is there anything to do with the system automatic update or Xcode component update? Thanks, I just want to find out where the problem is in case spend more money...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it may be possible. May be you have downloadd`iOS 6.0 Documentation Set` or`Mac OS X 10.6 Core Library`. Sometime it happens **after installing** or **updating** XCODE. You may found new updates and it **will automatically download** updates.

For checking this thing Go to `xcode -> prefrences -> Downloads -> Components`. check here it may possible your components are downloaded like this way.

[image]

Hope you will get your answer.

Comment: Oh my god, oh my god! That's it. I just installed the newest version of Xcode actually, and it did this to me! Aaaaaaaah!

Comment: Sometime it happens. You can forcefully quit this thing while running xcode.

Answer (score 2):

This is just my opinion. Your iPhone creates a Wi-Fi hotspot. Your Mac is connected to Wi-Fi, not 3G network. Maybe Macs are not smart enough to understand that they connected to Wi-Fi "modem", which actually is connected 3G. So they still doing background updates. Although, I never had such problem with iPhone as a modem. It can depend on OS version also. I have 10.8.2.

Use activity monitor to track apps which do some networking. Install local firewall app like a Little Snitch and block some apps (or hosts) when you iPhone-networking.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you. But I have checked the system Updates folder in the /Library, No file was downloaded during that time.